# Make regex that replaces a comma separated list (e.g. "one,two,three") with "one, two, and three" if 3+ items, or "one and two" if 2 items

Tags: regex, google-sheets, regexp-replace

**The problem:**

I am struggling to create a regular expression (*in Google Sheets*) that converts a comma separated list into a standard English readable format.

**Input/Output examples:**

When a list contains 3+ items such as `one,two,three` then it should return `one, two, and three` and if a list contains 2 items such as `one,two` then it should return `and and two` and if a list contains only 1 item such as `one` then it should return `one`

**My JavaScript approach:**

Here's how I (probably inefficiently) achieved the same thing with a single dimensional array in JavaScript:

```
function joinWith(arr, sep, lastsep){ // e.g. joinWith(listOfNames, ",", "and")
  sep += ' ', lastsep = ' ' + lastsep + ' ';
  var rtn = [arr.slice(0, -1).join(sep) + (arr.length > 2 ? sep : ''), arr.slice(-1)[0]].join(arr.length < 2 ? '' : lastsep);
  return rtn;
}
```

**In other words:**

This is what I think I want to do (unless I'm missing something of course):

1. Remove any padding surrounding commas.
2. Add a space after each comma.
3. Precede the last item with "and ".

**Here's what I've tried using REGEXREPLACE**

```
=REGEXREPLACE(A1, ",\s*([^,]+)$", ", and $1")
```

This is as close as I've gotten to the outcome I want, but when there are 2 items in the list, it inserts a comma and I don't want that to happen unless there are 3 or more items in the list.

[image: Here's a screenshot of my test case.]

**Overkill inelegant method**

And then I went with the overkill approach, but I would prefer something more elegant in a single regular expression:

```
=REGEXREPLACE(A1, ",\s*([^,]+)$", IF(COLUMNS(SPLIT(A1, ",")) > 2, ",", "") & " and $1")
```

[image: And here's the screenshot of that approach.]

Comment: Firstly, regex does “do” anything; it only matches. You need app code to make changes. Also, regex isn’t necessarily more or less “efficient” than code. What’s wrong with what you’ve got?

Comment: @Bohemian I am using the REGEXREPLACE function in Google Sheets, and I would rather not have a custom scripted formula if it can be done reasonably with built-in functions.

Comment: @Bohemian Why is this question on hold? I find it perfectly reasonable and answerable. And generally in Google Sheets formula-based solutions are considered more elegant than script-based solutions.

Comment: @ttarchala this site is not a code writing service; no attempt has been made by OP. Further, there is (apparently) a working solution.

Comment: @Bohemian How can you say there has been no attempt by OP when he posts a piece of code inside his question? It's not a formula, but that's probably why he's asking his question, maybe he doesn't even know how to start converting the JS into the pure functional world of GS formulas. Considering that this is a new poster, who already put some considerable effort into writing his question, I find this kind of moderator activism misguided and likely to put off new people from posting on SE.

Comment: @Matthew To overcome this sad bureaucratic moderator activism, please post your (failed) REGEXREPLACE attempts in your question. Then maybe he will un-hold it and we can post the answers.

Comment: @ttarchala I can confidently and accurately say there is no attempt, because well, there is no attempt. OP posted some code, but it's irrelevant to the question, which is about Google Sheets and its REGEXREPLACE function. OP could start with [the documentation](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098245?hl=en), then move on to [some examples](https://infoinspired.com/google-docs/spreadsheet/google-sheets-regexreplace-function/) and a [regex tutorial](https://www.regular-expressions.info/), then after making an attempt, post *that* code with a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Bohemian I have added my best attempts at tackling the problem using regular expressions in Google Sheets. Please reopen this so I can get a little more direction from people who may be better at regular expressions than I am.

Comment: it's not inserting a comma... you are: there's a comma in your replacement expression! Try this `=REGEXREPLACE(A1, ",\s*([^,]+)$", " and $1")`

Comment: @Bohemian I actually want it to have the comma before the "and" unless there are 2 items in the list, in which case I would not want a comma.

Comment: @Matthew Yes, I realise that now. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55012616/256196) for some code that should work.

Answer (score 1):

One convention for punctuation is that there's no comma before the `"and"` in a list. ie `"item1, item2 and item3"` is the correct way to format a list. If readers want that, then *don’t* do the final step. This code also does not use look arounds, because they are not supported by Google Sheets.

There are *three* operations you are trying to do as *one*... just use separate operations.

Operations:

1. correctly format commas and whitespace
2. replace last comma with "and"
3. place comma before "and" when there’s more than 2 terms

Use nested calls to `REGEXREPLACE`, one call for each operation:

```
=REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(A1, "\s*, \s*", ", "), ", ([^,]+)$", ", and $1"), "^([^,]+), and ([^,]+)$", "$1 and $2")
```

If you always want the comma before the “and”, don’t perform the outer-most operation.

<sub>Disclaimer: This answer was thumbed in via my phone, so it may not work correctly or even compile, but there’s a good chance it will work.</sub>

Comment: @bjm damn... I was hoping I could get away with less code. Now you’ve made me code both solutions! :)

Comment: Nice!  I probably would have weaseled out of it by just changing the wording, but you took the wombat route and wrote more code. :)